# Debug WildFly Project in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Is it possible to debug the WildFly server project in Netbeans ?

I tried to do this, and always failed. The WildFly server show this error message: java.net.MalformedURLException: For input string: "8080undefined".

I noticed that it tried to run the appliction on wrong port (instead the 8080, it ran on 8080undefined). Browsing: http://localhost:8080undefined

Thanks before.

Answer (score 0):

Usually debugging port is 8787 on Wildfly.

I see no issue with debugging with Wildfly and Netbeans.

Mere the fact, it should not be IDE related functionality.

I feel you will face the same issue in Eclipse or any other IDE.

In order to have it fully working, make sure the server is started in debug mode.

Regarding the MalformedUrl Exception, I feel it is caused by a code issue.
If this is the case, than you should write on StackOverFlow for help.